# When does not occur $\partial X \subset X- \operatorname{int }X$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

What is the counterexample that 
$$\partial X \subset X- \operatorname{int} X$$
does not occur. Where $X\subset M$, $M=(M,d)$ is a metric space, $\partial X$ is the boundary of $X$ and $\operatorname{int} X$ is the set of all interior points of the set $X$.

I know that the contrary inclusion is valid.

Comment: A boundary point of $X$ need not be a point of $X$. In fact, one definition of boundary point is $\text{cl} X - \text{int} X$, so any counterexample must come from an example where $X \subsetneq \text{cl} X$.

Comment: Any open set with nonempty boundary will do, won't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X = \Bbb{R} \smallsetminus \{0\}$.  Here $\partial X = \{0\}$, but $0 \not \in X$.  Notice that $X = \mathrm{int}\,X$ here.

Answer (score 1):

$M=\Bbb R$ and $X=\Bbb Q$ (usual metric).

$\partial X=\Bbb R$ which is not a subset of $X-\emptyset=\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

1. If $X$ is not closed then $\emptyset \ne \overline X - X=$ $\overline X\cap (M-X)$ $\subset \overline X\cap \overline {M-X}=$ $\partial X.$

So if $X$ is not closed then $\overline X-X$ is a non-empty subset of $\partial X$ which is disjoint from $X,$ so $\partial X$ cannot be a subset of $X,$ and ( a fortiori ) $\partial X$ cannot be a subset of $X-int(X).$

2. In any kind of topological space $M,$ if $X\subset M$ then the trio $int(X),\,  int (M-X),\,  \partial X$ are pair-wise disjoint and their union is $M.$

   So if $X$ is closed then $$\partial X=\partial X-int (X)=$$ $$=(\overline X\cap \overline {M-X})-int(X)=$$ $$=(X\cap \overline {M-X})-int(X)=$$ $$=(X-int(X))\cap (\overline {M-X}-int (X))\subset$$ $$\subset X-int(X).$$

In conclusion, $\partial X \subset X-int(X)$ iff $X$ is closed.

3. Appendix. On further inspection, for any $X\subset M,$ we have $X\cap int(M-X)=\emptyset$ and $X\cap int(X)=int(X),$ so $$X=X\cap M=X\cap [int(X)\cup int(M-X)\cup \partial X]=$$ $$=[X\cap int(X)]\cup [X\cap int (M-X)]\cup [X\cap \partial X]=$$ $$=int(X)\cup (X\cap \partial X).$$ Therefore $$X-int(X)=[int(X)\cup (X\cap \partial X)]-int X=$$ $$=(X\cap \partial X)-int(X)\subset \partial X.$$ Applying this to 2. (above) we see that if $X$ is closed then $\partial X=X-int(X).$ And in summary, for any $X$ we have $$\partial X\subset X-int(X) \iff \partial X=X-int(X) \iff X=\overline X.$$